# How do continue/end this infinite limit expression? Shall I use the Reciprocal Rule? - Almost finished

Tags: limits, infinity

[The picture of my work is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKctQ.jpg)

I am almost done with this, but I do not know how to end it? Shall I use the Reciprocal rule?

Comment: In future, please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site/33183#33183) to typeset your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final step is to write it as
$$
\frac{\lim_{x \to \infty}2+\frac{4}{x}+\frac{1}{x^3}}{\lim_{x \to \infty}5+\frac{2}{x^2}}=\frac{2}{5} \, .
$$
If you were doing things completely rigorously, then you would also have to justify why
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}2+\frac{4}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}=2
$$
and likewise for the denominator. One approach would be to use the sum rule:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}2+\frac{4}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to \infty}2+\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{4}{x}+\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{x^2}
$$
and then use the formal definition of a limit. For instance, $\lim_{x \to\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}=0$ if and only if
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists N>0 : x>N \implies \left|\frac{1}{x^2}\right|<\varepsilon
$$
If we take $N=1/\sqrt{\varepsilon}$, then
\begin{align}
&x > 1/\sqrt{\varepsilon} \\
\implies & 1/x < \sqrt{\varepsilon} \\
\implies & 1/x^2 < \varepsilon
\end{align}
as required.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: @Hadse: No worries! I'm glad I could help.